# Can I filter out songs downloaded to device from Apple Music?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediapickercontroller, apple-music, apple-musickit

I have a `MPMediaPickerController` showing songs available on the device to use for sending to other users on my app. I've filtered out Cloud items, but I also want to filter out songs from Apple Music that have been made "available offline."

```
-(void)openMusic:(NSNotification *)notification {

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"myMusic"]){

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.75 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
            mediaPicker.delegate = self;
            mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;
            mediaPicker.showsCloudItems = NO;
            [self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
        });

    }


}
```

Currently, it's still showing all downloaded Apple Music tracks. How can I filter them out?

Comment: I still don't know how to hide Apple Music items that have been made available offline, but I did discover that when an Apple Music item has been downloaded to the device the track's `itemURL = nil` so perhaps that can be used to filter them out of `MPMediaPickerController`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502806/mpmediapickercontroller-showsclouditems-seems-to-do-nothing#answer-22920187), if you use:

`picker.showsCloudItems = NO;`

You will get the list of songs that either were **manually downloaded** in the Music app or songs that **were streamed and therefore cached**. 
However, since [Apple Music songs are DRM protected](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph19639?locale=en_GB), to display only songs downloaded locally, you need to add this line, too:

[`picker.showsItemsWithProtectedAssets = NO;`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediapickercontroller?language=objc)

Comment: perfect solution to filter out songs downloaded to device from Apple Music..